# SuperTest - App is not defined

Tags: javascript, express, mocha.js, supertest

I'm new to test driven development and am trying to use supertest to teach myself. I'm confused as to why I keep getting the error "app is not defined"? It is from my calls to request(app) which I have bolded below.  I tried to look up the documentation but there doesn't seem to be much.  All of my routes are in a file called "middleware", and that file starts like this:

```
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var helpers = require('./helpers.js'); // our custom middleware
    var db = require('../DB/DB.js');
    var router = require('../routes.js');
    var path = require('path');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var gm = require('gm');


    module.exports = function (app, express) {}
```

---

The actual file where I use supertest to test the middleware file's routes:

```
    var chai = require('chai')
    var assert = chai.assert;
    var should = chai.should();
    var expect = chai.expect;
    var helpers = require("../config/helpers.js");
    var middleware = require("../config/middleware.js");
    // for when we eventually want to test against mock data
    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path');
    var supertest = require("supertest")(middleware);

describe('middleware API', function() {


  it('responds with binary data', function(done) {
    var imagePath = path.join(__dirname, '/../assets/drawings/', userName + '.png');
    **request(app)**
      .get(imagePath)
      .expect(201)
      .expect('Content-Type', 'image.png')
      .parse(binaryParser)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        if (err) return done(err);

        // binary response data is in res.body as a buffer
        assert.ok(Buffer.isBuffer(res.body));
        console.log("res=", res.body);

        done();
      });
  });

  it('sends back one image', function(done) {
    **request(app)**
      .get('/game/')
      .expect(201)
      .expect('Content-Type', 'image.png')
      .expect('Content-Length', '1')
      .parse(binaryParser)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        if (err) return done(err);

        // binary response data is in res.body as a buffer
        assert.ok(Buffer.isBuffer(res.body));
        console.log("res=", res.body);

        done();
      })

  })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the top of your file you need to define express and app, ie:

```
var express        = require('express'),
    app            = express();
```

Also, make sure that you've installed express, ie thru command line in node:

```
npm install express --save
```

(using "--save" adds it to your package.json file, which makes it easy to keep track of the version, etc, but also installs automatically if somebody else installs your project using npm install).